# C++: virtual functions with multiple derivations

Tags: c++, function, inheritance, virtual

I have the following structure:

```
class A{
public:
    virtual void fn() = 0;
} ;

class B : public A{
public:
    virtual void fn(){
       //implB
    }
} ;

class Base{
     //whatever
} ;

class C : public Base,public B{
public:
    virtual void fn(){
        //implC
    }
} ;

B* instance = new C();
(*instance).fn()
```

This seems to call `implB` and not `implC`. Is this normal?
I'd like to call implementation `implC` of `fn`, is there a way to do it?

Comment: If I complete in the obvious (for me) way, I get the expected result of calling C::fn(). Please give the full code allowing to reproduce.

Comment: When you have shown should call the C version once you write code that actually compiles. (fn should have a return value: are you sure the signature of B and C are the same? If one has different parameters or is const while the other isn't, they are not the same).

Comment: To make it compile: 1. return type for fn, 2. end class definitions with a semicolon. 3. put the body at the end into main() not at file scope.

Comment: Just make it compiled and ran it in VS2010, clearly fn() in C is called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right, C::fn() is called when my example is ran alone. My problem actually was that I was dynamically loading this class (C) with ros:pluginlib (http://ros.org/wiki/pluginlib) so the multiple inheritance issue is probably coming from there. That's a completly different issue I'll have to look into.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you call it like this:

```
instance->fn();
```

but your version works as well.

Since you have a instance of `C`, `C::fn()` will be called.

Comment: no idea who gave you a downvote (or why) - some people are too quick to downvote round here.... Have an upvote to cancel it